# Typescript Error:Cannot read property 'length' of undefined while running ng-serve

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

padmavathi@K1037 C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard

> ng serve
>   Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at createSourceFile (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8980:109)
>       at parseSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8940:26)
>       at Object.parseSourceFile (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8899:26)
>       at Object.createSourceFile (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:8727:29)
>       at new TypeScriptFileRefactor (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\refactor.js:25:35)
>       at Object.resolveEntryModuleFromMain (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\entry_resolver.js:108:18)
>       at AotPlugin._setupOptions (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:129:58)
>       at new AotPlugin (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:37:14)
>       at Object.exports.getWebpackNonAotConfigPartial (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\angular-cli\models\webpack-build-typescript.js:20:13)
>       at new NgCliWebpackConfig (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\angular-cli\models\webpack-config.js:23:42)
>       at Class.run (C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\angular-cli\tasks\serve-webpack.js:20:22)
>       at C:\Users\padmavathi\Downloads\phototype-development\web\dashboard\node_modules\angular-cli\commands\serve.js:102:26
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Comment: Hi Elluru, this looks like a bug unrelated to your code. Try a google search for "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at createSourceFile"

Comment: include your code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
It turned out that i had made a mistake in my angular-cli.json file.

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "name": "angular3"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",/* This must point to your source file locations*/
      "outDir": "dist",/* your output folder */
```

If the source folder is not found/readable or no source files are found, then the length of files is undefined.